# How to remove None when iterating through a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have this two unequal lists and i'm using itertools to loop through them and i'm trying to use the filter function to  remove the None generated in List1 so that at the end of the day a contains only two elements instead of three (counting the none) but i keep getting this error: Type error: NoneType object is not iterable

```
import itertools

List1  = [['a'],['b']]
List2 = ['A','b','C']

l = list(itertools.chain(*List1))
print(l)

for a, b in itertools.zip_longest((b for a in List1 for b in a),List2):
    filter(None, a)
    print(a,b)
```

Comment: Why are you using `zip_longest`? Doesn't `zip` already do exactly what you need?

Comment: `a` is just one element, not a list, and at the end it is `None`. Also, if you want to "filter out" the none, what will then be `a` for the third element in `b`? Either use `zip_longest` with `None`, or use just `zip`

Comment: @tobias_k thats the problem i want the third element but i don't want a to have a value. truth is, the real list i'm implementing is made up of objects so trying to get a property of None throws an exception saying the object dosen't have that attribute

Comment: "i want the third element but i don't want a to have a value" Well, what do you want that element to be, then? `None` seems to be a good option, you just have to check whether its none before doing operations on it. Another variant might be to use a special instance of your class as a sentinel value instead of None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you want. As I understand the question and the comments, you want to use `izip_longest` to combine the lists, but without any `None` elements in the result.

This will filter the `None` from the zipped 'slices' of the lists and print only the non-`None` values. But note that this way you can not be sure whether, e.g., the first element in the `non_none` list came from the first list or the second or third.

```
a = ["1", "2"]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
c = ["x", "y", "z"]

for zipped in izip_longest(a, b, c):
    non_none = filter(None, zipped)
    print non_none
```

Output:

```
('1', 'a', 'x')
('2', 'b', 'y')
('c', 'z')
('d',)
```

BTW, what your `filter(None, a)` does: It filters the `None` values from your `a`, i.e. from the *strings* `"a"` and `"b"` (which does not do much, as they contain no `None` values), until it fails for the last value, as `None` is not iterable. Also, it discards the result anyway, as you do not bind it to a variable. `filter` does *not* alter the original list, but returns a filtered copy!

Comment: FILTER considers 0 and None as equivalent and as such, the results could be incorrect for the user's purposes (if 0 is important).  Using `filter(lambda x: x if x is not None, zipped)` is a 'better' answer in that instance (ignoring memory, speed objectives etc etc).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `zip`?

```
for a, b in zip((b for a in List1 for b in a),List2):
    print(a,b)
```

However, if you really insist on using `zip_longest`, you don't need to use `filter` to remove None values. You just need an `if`.

```
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest((b for a in List1 for b in a),List2):
    if a is None: continue
    print(a,b)
```

Comment: I don't think this suggestion is 'strong' enough as zip and zip_longest can and will be used for more than just 2 lists.   It will be very cumbersome to use this methodology for 'n' lists where n > 2, no?    I think filtering or rebuilding the lists to exclude None values once zipped is the only way forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it

def grouper(inputs, n, fillvalue=None):
    iters = [iter(inputs)] * n
    interim = it.zip_longest(*iters, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    return interim

nums = range(23)
results = (list(grouper(nums, 4)))

finalanswer = []
for zipped in results:
    # non_none = tuple(filter(None, zipped))
    # unfortunately the line above filters 0 which is incorrect so instead use:
    non_none = tuple(filter(lambda x: x is not None, zipped))
    finalanswer.append(non_none)
print(finalanswer)
```

The code above uses zip_longest to illustrate generating zipped iterations of 'n' lists, irrespective of whether a corresponding entry exists in a given list or not --- and then strips out 'None' values --- noting that FILTER considers None and 0 as equivalent, so you have to use the 'lambda' version.